# Wifi file sharing on android 2.2

Tags: android, wifi, p2p

Hello i am making a project on P2P file sharing on android ...

There are Wifi APIs for android 4.0 .
But i am looking for something for android 2.2
Is there any APIs available for android 2.2 for wifi ?
Please help ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an app for this particular file sharing. and it's called File Share and can be found on google play

It is actually quite easy to use and it does I auto search for your out ip address

Have a good one and good luck

AJ